# Flash implementation of `<audio>` and `<video>` tags for HTML 5?

Tags: flash, video, audio, html

I am trying to convert our all-flash website to HTML 5.
But since so many users still use IE and other browsers that do not support HTML 5 yet,
I am looking for some flash media players that can replace `<audio>` and `<video>`. 
My google skill does not yield good results.
The flash media player should dispatch events specified at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_FireFox (or at least talk to javascript some how for those events).

Do you know a flash media player that can easily be embedded inside `<audio>` or `<video>` and talks to javascript for events?

Comment: The Audio and Video tags have been removed from the HTML5 specs anyway.

Comment: @TandemAdam: and yet it's still in the spec http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html (last update Oct 27) and being discussed in the HTML WG http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2009Nov/thread.html ? I think you're mistaken.

Comment: @TandenAdam The video element has never been removed from the spec.  There was originally a codec requirement which was dropped when the browsers couldn't agree on what it should be.  There has never been any substantial controversey over the audio element.

I'm not quite sure why this meme is still so persistent...

Answer (score 1):

you should use some server side for doing that. basically you check the user [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Agent) and if it's IE you just put your current flash based content. If it's firefox and other put the `HTML5` content.

*Note*: it also possible to use some `javascript` to achieve same goal.

Answer (score 1):

Any instance of Adobe Flash Player within an HTML page would not be able to parse the tags within the page themselves... the tags are read by the browser, which invokes the plugin, and so the browser would notice VIDEO/AUDIO tags 'way before the Player would have a chance to change things.

But have you looked at some of the conditional markup/script approaches to determining browser capability? Kroc Camen had one of the first big attempts on this subject, and I'm not certain of other entrants in the field right now, but here's a starting point:
http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

(I'm not sure about "all Flash sites" in general, because Flash is generally used within HTML, but an "all 'HTML5' site" would seem even shakier than that, at least at this stage. Your decision though.)